# Powershell cmdlet parameter definition contain parameter name starts with $ creating change in default be haviour

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet

```
function Test1 {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param (
        [Parameter( Position = 0, ValueFromPipeline = $true,   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true, Mandatory = $false)]
        [String]
        ${$count},
        [Parameter( Position = 1,ValueFromPipeline = $true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true, Mandatory = $false)]
        [String]
        ${$inlinecount}
    )
    Process { 
         Write-Host "TEST1 ${$count} : ${$inlinecount}"
    }
}
```

Calling the function as below

```
PS> Test1 10 20
    TEST1 10:20
PS> Test1 -$count 10
    TEST1   : 10
PS> Test1 -$inlinecount 100
    TEST1   : 100
PS> Test1  -$count 10 -$inlinecount 100
    Error Test1 : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '-'.
```

I am not able to specify only one value, i.e only $count, it is taking 'Test1 $count 10' with $count as the value for $count, and 10 as the value for $inlinecount. I don't wanted to remove the $ prefixed with each parameter name. Also not able to specify both parameter values by name

How can i change the parameter definition, so that following will results

```
PS> Test1 -$count 10
    TEST1 10 :
PS> Test1 -$inlinecount 100
    TEST1   :100
PS> Test1  -$count 10 -$inlinecount 100
    TEST1   10:100
```

Comment: Use splating: `$p = @{ '$inlinecount' = 100 }; Test1 @p`

Answer (score 0):

I think this might clarify some things for you:

```
Function Start-Test1 {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
        [String[]]$Count,
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName )]
        [String]$InlineCount
    )

    Process { 
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Count = $Count
            InlineCount = $InlineCount
        }
        Write-Verbose "TEST1 ${$count} : ${$inlinecount}"
    }
}

# No parameters, empty result
Start-Test1

# Only one parameter, output Count = 1
Start-Test1 -Count 1

# Only one parameter, output InlineCount = A
Start-Test1 -InlineCount A

# Two parameters, output Count = 1 InlineCount = A
Start-Test1 -Count 1 -InlineCount A


# Multiple input for Count
Start-Test1 -Count 1, 2, 3
```

The dollar sign is only used once in the `Param` clause for each parameter. It makes it also easier to read.

Defining positions, with `Position = 1` and so on.. is only needed when the parameters are out of order. In this case, they can be omitted. The same goes for `Mandatory = $false`, when it is omitted, PowerShell assumes by default that the parameter is not mandatory. But when you write `Mandatory` it assumes you mean that the parameter is mandatory. So no need to use the boolean `$true/$false`.

In case you want to accept multiple arguments for one parameter, you can use `[]`. As an example `[String]$Name` accepts only one name, but `[String[]]$Name` will accept multiple names.

**Some tips:**

Some remarks, always use a correct function name. You can find the verbs with `Get-Verb`. These are the allowed verbs you can use.

Try to output an object (`array`, `PSCustomObject`, `HashTable`, ...) whenever you can, not just `Write-Host` because that's only useful for visualizing output in the console. For this, it's better to use `Write-Verbose`. You can then run your function with `Start-Test -Verbose` only in case you want extra information to be displayed on the console.

Comment: The issue i mentioned arrived due to ${$count}} and ${$inlinecount}} , there are two $, if there is only one $ there won't any issue (i know about it).. I wanted to keep two $, and solve the problem

Comment: Why would you want to have two dollar signs in your parameter definition?